# Aligment image and text with class in flex container item

Tags: css

I am trying create my own basic grid system with css flex. I want use classes for text and image alignment in flex item container.

I need help understanding the best way to do this.

This is currently what I have:

```css
.flex-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:#330066;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin : 5px;
  background: tomato;
}

.flex-footer > .item > div {
  display: table;
}

.middle-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item > .bottom-center {
  align-self: flex-end;
  /*display : table-cell;*/
  /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
  /*align-items: flex-end;*/
  /*align-self: flex-end; */
  /*align-content: flex-end;*/
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.order-1 { order: 1; }
.order-2 { order: 2; }
.order-3 { order: 3; }


.col-4 {
  width: 25%;  
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-footer">
    
  <div class="item col-4 order-3">
  <div class="top-left">text (top left) a</div>
  <div class="middle-left">text (middle left)</div>
  <div class="bottom left">text (bottom left)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item col-4 order-1">
  <div class="bottom-center">text (middle center)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item col-4 order-2">
  <div class="">text (top right)</div>
  <div class="middle-center">image (middle center)</div>
  <div>ul/litext </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

My jsfiddle example is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/svwp24m6/

Comment: @Jackson thank you for your edit. My English is not good for grammer sentences. How did you make code snippet? If you explain or if you send a link of explanatory information page, I can use for my next questions.

Comment: you should narrow down your question to a particular issue. As it stands now, there are too many 'what-if' variables to consider for answers to be clear or concise

Comment: @webmaster see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `display: flex` to all `.item`s too.

Here is what I understood that you wanted to do, and some examples of how flex can do it.

The `margin` in `.item` is making the items become bigger than the width of `.flex-footer`. I rarely use margin in flex elements, because I need to take that into account (with `calc()`) when setting `flex-basis`. Margins are namely not accounted for in flex containers, sadly.

```css
.flex-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:#330066;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin : 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* to include padding in the element's width */
  background: tomato;
}

.item.order-2 {
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item.order-3 {
   justify-content: left;
}

/*.flex-footer > .item > div {
  display: table;
}*/

 .top {
   align-self: start;
 }

 .middle {
   align-self: center;
 }

 .bottom {
   align-self: end;
 }

.order-1 { order: 1; }
.order-2 { order: 2; }
.order-3 { order: 3; }


.col-4 > div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  /*width: 25%;  */
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-footer">
    
  <div class="item col-4 order-3">
    <div class="top left">text (top left) a</div>
    <div class="middle left">text (middle left)</div>
    <div class="bottom left">text (bottom left)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item col-4 order-1">
    <div class="middle center">text (middle center)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item col-4 order-2">
    <div class="top right">text (top right)</div>
    <div class="middle center">image (middle center)</div>
    <div>ul/litext </div>
  </div>

</div>
```